# Saving images without encoding them with laravel/intervention

Tags: laravel

Sometimes i need to place images somewhere without encoding them or touching on the quality, For example:

The content-length of this image is 27661,But when i use `save()` method it become twice as its size on the disk:

```
// the original size is 27661
Image::make('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg')->save('Example.jpg', 100)
//outpute size on the disk: 63420
```

Is it possible to just save images and don't encoding them with this library ?

Comment: why would you use this library then ... just download the remote file, you don't need intervention involved

Comment: Because this lib can handle images as path/binray/stream/remote, i want to avoid duplication as possible